# Find and replace on XML using Visual studio

Tags: xml, find

i saw a code on YT that finds and replaces Text that you input on rich text box

my problem is that i want a batch find and replace in 1-click, that i would input the text, from many and long xmls, open that xml on the visual studio and do it find and replace

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
    <group name="Animals">
        <option name="height-cat" value="8.00" />
        <option name="height-dog" value="15.00" />
        <option name="height-turtle" value="4.00" />
    </group>
    <group name="Place">
        <option name="beauty-shop-far" value="140.000000" />
        <option name="coffee-shop-far" value="450.000000" />
        <option name="market-limit-distance" value="150.000000" />
    </group>
</xml>
```

Comment: Please include the code in the question, no screenshots

Comment: Hi scyx - welcome to stackoverflow. Please include what you've tried so far and what your specific error is. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

' Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click RichTextBox1.Text = Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
 MsgBox(" ' " & TextBox1.Text & " ' " & " Has been replaced with:" & " ' " & TextBox2.Text & " ' ")
 End Sub'
i dont want to use the text box to input words, instead input as whole string  and will be replaced as  and also the source(xml that would b edited) would be open file(.xml)
e.g. '  '

BTW. what datatype is this, i want to delare this as it is (less-grater than sign,Quotation marks, included)